# Using Google script to round to $XX.99

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a piece of code in my Google Spreadsheet script that adds a new column ("RRP") and inputs a value that is another column * 1.18. So it takes the price (skuData[i][5]) and multiplies it by 1.18.

I would like to round up that resulting value to the nearest X.99.

I can easily do this with a spreadsheet formula, but I'm at a loss to try and get the script to do it.

```
function filterSheet()
 {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shSKU=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var skuData=shSKU.getDataRange().getValues();

  var finalData=[];
  var i,j;
  finalData[0]=[];
  for(i=0;i<skuData[0].length;i++)
    finalData[0].push(skuData[0][i]);

  // new column to be added
      finalData[0].push("RRP");

      var count=1;
  for(i=1;i<skuData.length;i++)
  {

  // Getting Data into Array
    for(j=0;j<skuData[i].length;j++)
    {
      finalData[count].push(skuData[i][j]);
   }


  // Multiply price by 1.18 and enter it into the new column
      finalData[count].push(skuData[i][5]*(1.8));
    count++;
   }
  }
```

If skuData[i][5] is 10, the output in the new column (RRP) should be 11.99

Comment: Can you share the structure of your spreadsheet? This code alone doesn't run on its own as only the first element of `finalData` has been initialised as an array so `finalData[count].push()` throws a read error on undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Math.ceil()` on your data to get to the nearest Integer and then subtract 0.01 from that:

```
var x = Math.ceil(skuData[i][5]*(1.18));
finalData[count].push(x - 0.01);
```